# How can I combine my Models together to make it work?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have tried to find a way to get all my models in one class many different ways but nothing has worked so here is my code could anyone help?
It works currently but I want to have better practice because I am new to MVVM

this app is taking input in a text box and returning it in a text block

Model:

DateEntry.cs

```
/// <summary>
/// Entity Class for the Date 
/// </summary>
namespace FumeHood1._0._2.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    public class DateEntry : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDataErrorInfo
    {
        private string _date;

        public DateEntry(string testDate)
        //Initializes a new instance of the LabelDataEntry Class
        {
            Date = testDate;
        }

        //Gets or Sets the Date

        public string Date
        {
            get { return _date; }
            set
            {
                _date = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Date");
            }
        }


        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
        #endregion

        #region IDataErrorInfo Members
        public string Error
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }
        public string this[string columnName]
        {
            get
            {
                if (columnName == "Date")
                {
                    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Date))
                    {
                        Error = "Name cannot be null or empty";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Error = null;
                    }
                }
                return Error;
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

RoomNumberEntry.cs

```
/// <summary>
/// Entity Class for the Room Numbers
/// </summary>
namespace FumeHood1._0._2.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    public class RoomNumberEntry : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDataErrorInfo
    {
        private string _roomNumber;

        public RoomNumberEntry(string testRoomNumber)
        //Initializes a new instance of the LabelDataEntry Class
        {
            RoomNumber = testRoomNumber;
        }

        //Gets or Sets the Room Number

        public string RoomNumber
        {
            get { return _roomNumber; }
            set
            {
                _roomNumber = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("RoomNumber");
            }
        }


        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
        #endregion

        #region IDataErrorInfo Members
        public string Error
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }
        public string this[string columnName]
        {
            get
            {
                if (columnName == "RoomNumber")
                {
                    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(RoomNumber))
                    {
                        Error = "Name cannot be null or empty";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Error = null;
                    }
                }
                return Error;
            }
        }
        #endregion

    }
}
```

ViewModel:
MainViewModel.cs

```
namespace FumeHood1._0._2.ViewModels
{
    using System;
    using FumeHood1._0._2.Models;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Windows.Input;
    using FumeHood1._0._2.Commands;
    using FumeHood1._0._2.Views;

    internal class MainViewModel
    {
        private DateEntry _labelDataEntry;
        private RoomNumberEntry _roomNumberEntry;
        private ReturnViewModel _childViewModel;


        ///Initializes a new instance of the DateViewModel
        public MainViewModel()
        {
            DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
            _labelDataEntry = new DateEntry(today.ToString("d"));
            _roomNumberEntry = new RoomNumberEntry("5");
            UpdateCommand = new LabelDataEntryCommands(this);

        }



        //Gets the LabelDataEntry instance
        public DateEntry LabelDataEntry
        {
            get { return _labelDataEntry; }
        }

        public RoomNumberEntry RoomNumberEntry
        {
            get { return _roomNumberEntry; }
        }

        //Gets the UpdateCommand for the ViewModel
        public ICommand UpdateCommand
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }

        //Save the changes to the LabelDataEntry
        public void SaveChanges()
        {
            DateInfoView view = new DateInfoView();
            view.DataContext = _childViewModel;

            _childViewModel.Date = LabelDataEntry.Date;
            _childViewModel.RoomNumber = RoomNumberEntry.RoomNumber;
            view.ShowDialog();
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to merge classes into one .cs file?

Comment: I am asking how should I combine them so they still work because I am using the ctor in both